# How to go from one tab panel to another in bs4 dashboard in shiny r

Tags: r, shiny

I want to update tab panels using radio buttons in bs4TabSetPanel using updatebs4TabSetPanel(). I have done this multiple number of times in shiny dashboard, however I am unable to do it in bs4Dash. I am uploading a sample code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

home<-bs4TabSetPanel(
  id = "tabset1",
  side = "left",

  bs4TabPanel(
    tabName = "Tab 1",
    active = TRUE,
    fluidRow(
      box(radioButtons("abc", label = "Please select an option", 
                       choices = c("Go to tab 2" = "G2", "Go to tab 3" = "G3"), selected = character()))
    )
  ),
  bs4TabPanel(
    tabName = "Tab 2",
    active = FALSE,
    fluidRow(
      h1("Welcome to tab 2")
    )
  ),
  bs4TabPanel(
    tabName = "Tab 3",
    active = FALSE,
    fluidRow(
      h1("Welcome to tab 3")
    )
  )
)

ui<- bs4DashPage(
  navbar = bs4DashNavbar(),
  sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(),
  controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
  footer = bs4DashFooter(),
  title = "test",
  body = bs4DashBody(
    home
  )
)

server<- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$abc,{
    if (input$abc == "G2"){
      updatebs4TabSetPanel(session, "tabset1", selected = "Tab 2")
    } else{
      updatebs4TabSetPanel(session, "tabset1", selected = "Tab 3")
    } 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Bijurika in bs4Dash you need to use the numeric position of the tab rather than the tab name.

This should work, I just changed 'selected = "Tab 2"' to 'selected = 2' (and the same for "Tab 3")

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bs4Dash)

home<-bs4TabSetPanel(
  id = "tabset1",
  side = "left",

  bs4TabPanel(
    tabName = "Tab 1",
    active = TRUE,
    fluidRow(
      box(radioButtons("abc", label = "Please select an option", 
                       choices = c("Go to tab 2" = "G2", "Go to tab 3" = "G3"), selected = character()))
    )
  ),
  bs4TabPanel(
    tabName = "Tab 2",
    active = FALSE,
    fluidRow(
      h1("Welcome to tab 2")
    )
  ),
  bs4TabPanel(
    tabName = "Tab 3",
    active = FALSE,
    fluidRow(
      h1("Welcome to tab 3")
    )
  )
)

ui<- bs4DashPage(
  navbar = bs4DashNavbar(),
  sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(),
  controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
  footer = bs4DashFooter(),
  title = "test",
  body = bs4DashBody(
    home
  )
)

server<- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$abc,{
    if (input$abc == "G2"){
      updatebs4TabSetPanel(session, "tabset1", selected = 2)
    } else{
      updatebs4TabSetPanel(session, "tabset1", selected = 3)
    } 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```